# "dynamic" where statement in sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, case

I need to pass two different `WHERE` statements based on a result in the select statement. My base query is the following

```
SELECT table1.taskID, 
    table1.startTime, 
    table1.endTime, 
    table1.everyMinutes, 
    table3.dlid, 
    table3.run 
FROM table1
JOIN table2
    ON table1.taskID = table2.taskID
LEFT JOIN table3
    ON table1.taskID = table3.taskID
WHERE table2.active = '1'
ORDER BY taskID ASC
```

What I am struggling with is if `table3.run = '1'`, then I need to include the following

```
CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) IN (SELECT dldate FROM table4 WHERE dlid = table3.dlid)
```

if `table3.run = '0'` I need to have the following

```
CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) NOT IN (SELECT dldate FROM table4 WHERE dlid = table3.dlid)
```

and finally, if table3.run = 'NULL' then I need to have neither of those statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT table1.taskID, 
    table1.startTime, 
    table1.endTime, 
    table1.everyMinutes, 
    table3.dlid, 
    table3.run 
FROM table1
JOIN table2
     ON table1.taskID = table2.taskID
LEFT JOIN table3
    ON table1.taskID = table3.taskID
WHERE table2.active = '1'
    AND (
            (table3.run = '1' 
             and CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) 
             IN (SELECT dldate FROM table4 WHERE dlid = table3.dlid)) 

         or (table3.run = '0' 
             and CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) NOT IN 
            (SELECT dldate FROM table4 WHERE dlid = table3.dlid))

         or table3.run = 'NULL'   -- incredibly bad idea
         )
ORDER BY taskID ASC
```

Comment: How does that handle the case where `table3.run = 'NULL'`?

Comment: Look closer.  The OP specifically uses the string `'NULL'`, not a Real (TM) `NULL`.  Your code should use `table3.run = 'NULL'` to satisfy the OP, but instead you have used the equality test for `NULL` instead of `is NULL`.  (I'll let you use the wet noodle on the OP for having a string NULL.)

Comment: @HABO Who in their right mind would test for a string with a value of 'NULL'? That's almost as bad as `if if = then then then = else`, which is legal in some languages.  Thanks for your patience, I'm learning.

Comment: So the quoted values that look like small integers, or perhaps bits, don't bother you?  _Sigh._  `0`, `1` or `ERROR_SUCCESS`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.taskID, 
    table1.startTime, 
    table1.endTime, 
    table1.everyMinutes, 
    table3.dlid, 
    table3.run 
FROM table1
JOIN table2
     ON table1.taskID = table2.taskID
LEFT JOIN table3
    ON table1.taskID = table3.taskID
WHERE table2.active = '1' AND ( table3.run = 'NULL' or
  case when CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) IN (SELECT dldate FROM table4 WHERE dlid = table3.dlid) then '1'
    else '0'
    end = table3.run )
ORDER BY taskID ASC
```